# Помогите сравнить два массива типа String не используя стандартные методы сравнения

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Надо написать метод сравнения двух массивов типа String. Сделал проверки на длину массивов, на идентичность длины слов в ячейках массива. И теперь надо сравнить слова в одинаковых ячейках массива посимвольно и вот тут загвоздка. Вот что у меня пока получилось сделать:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String[] f1 = {"red", "black", "blue"};
    String[] s2 = {"red", "block", "blue"};

    System.out.println(compareStringArrays(f1, s2));

}

public static boolean compareStringArrays(String[] first, String[] second)throws Exception{
    if (first == null || second == null)
        throw new Exception("This object is not exist");

    if (first.length != second.length)
        throw new Exception("The length of arrays is not the same");

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
            if (i == j && first[i].length() != second[j].length()){
                return false;

            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
            if (i == j){
                for (int k = 0; k < first[i].length(); k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < second[j].length(); l++) {
                        if (k == l && ){

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

в мозгах понимаю, что надо  сравнить, а как это сделать не соображу ...
Заранее благодарю за ответ и объяснение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, сделайте менее грамоздкий пример. В противном случае Вы рискуете остаться без ответа. Людям сложно разбираться в Вашем коде, который вырван из контекста

Comment: Код не вырван из контекста. Это полный пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня получилось вот такое решение:

```
public static boolean compareStringArrays(String[] first, String[] second) throws Exception {
    if (first == null)
        return second == null;
    else if (second == null)
        return false;


    if (first.length != second.length)
        return false;

    int size = first.length;
    for (int indexOfString = 0; indexOfString < size; indexOfString++)
        if (getLength(first, indexOfString) != getLength(second, indexOfString))
            return false;
        else
            for (int indexOfSymbol = 0; indexOfSymbol < getLength(first, indexOfString); indexOfSymbol++)
                if (first[indexOfString].charAt(indexOfSymbol) != second[indexOfString].charAt(indexOfSymbol))
                    return false;

    return true;
}

private static int getLength(String[] array, int index) {
    return array[index] == null ? 0 : array[index].length();
}
```

Comment: Красивый код :)

Comment: Artem, круто... спасибо за помощь !!

Comment: Artem Konovalov, не могли бы подсказать, как будет выглядеть метод сравнения двух массивов с использованием дженерика ? Если сигнатура метода будет такой public <T> boolean compareArrays(T[] first, T[] second) ... Я не могу понять какой алгоритм сравнения будет, ведь для примитивных типов вроде int сравнивается нее так, как скажем тип String. Наверное надо как-то использовать классы обёртки, а как не пойму.

Comment: @YuriiS  каким образом вы хотите сравнивать T? Если не установить никакие ограничения на тип, то возможно только через ==. если же написать <T extends Comparable> то уже можно будет через compareTo. А для примитивов дженерики не будут работать, нужно будет явно, переопределять метод.

Comment: Artem Konovalov, вот я точно не понимаю, по заданию надо написать метод сравнения массивов с дженериком, как я уже выше написал, чтобы был универсальным для всех типов. Но я не соображу ни как , как его делать...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/izebit/80482319dd8586652761a63e543abe47

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы просто не сделать так ?

```
    // в будущем, вместо first.length надо вставить массив, с наибольшим
    // количеством item's
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++)  {
    // так как проверка на одинаковое количество букв уже есть, можно этот if 
    // упростить так                 
                    char[] firstWord = first[i].toCharArray();
                    char[] secondWord = second[i].toCharArray();

                    for(int i = 0; i < firstWord.length(); i++)
                    {
                      if(firstWord[i] != secondWord[i]) { return false; }
                    }
     } // если не возвратит false, то проверка выполнена удачно
```

Не лучшее решение (на скорую руку писал), но принцип Вы должны понять.

Comment: Поясните для чего нужно брать массив с наибольшим количеством item`s ?